# InvalidRecordException from Neo4J after a JVM crash

Tags: java, crash, neo4j

I'm running Neo4J 1.8 embedded, Java 6, on CentOS.

After a JVM crash I started getting a few exceptions of the following:

```
org.neo4j.graphdb.NotFoundException: Unable to load one or more relationships from Node[1169385]. This usually happens when relationships are deleted by someone else just as we are about to load them. Please try again.
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.NodeImpl.loadMoreRelationshipsFromNodeManager(NodeImpl.java:530)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.NodeImpl.getMoreRelationships(NodeImpl.java:415)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.NodeImpl.loadInitialRelationships(NodeImpl.java:368)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.NodeImpl.ensureRelationshipMapNotNull(NodeImpl.java:345)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.NodeImpl.getAllRelationshipsOfType(NodeImpl.java:195)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.NodeImpl.getRelationships(NodeImpl.java:247)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.NodeProxy.getRelationships(NodeProxy.java:92)
        at com.bizya.polosvc.neo4j.model.PersonImpl.getAllSelvesNoPropsLoad(PersonImpl.java:1303)
        at com.bizya.polosvc.neo4j.model.PathsFinderImpl.findPaths(PathsFinderImpl.java:189)
        at com.bizya.polosvc.neo4j.model.PathsFinderImpl.findPaths(PathsFinderImpl.java:49)
        at com.bizya.server.services.ReachabilityService.findReachabilities(ReachabilityService.java:82)
        at com.bizya.server.widget.BrowsingPageBuilder.buildAdditionalResultsModel(BrowsingPageBuilder.java:97)
        at com.bizya.server.widget.ContextBrowsingPageBuilder.buildAdditionalResultsModel(ContextBrowsingPageBuilder.java:81)
        at com.bizya.server.widget.ContextBrowsingPageBuilder.buildAdditionalResultsModel(ContextBrowsingPageBuilder.java:71)
        at com.bizya.server.widget.servlet.NetworkServlet.doGet(NetworkServlet.java:139)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
        at com.bizya.server.widget.servlet.MasterWidgetServlet.handleAuthorizedUser(MasterWidgetServlet.java:167)
        at com.bizya.server.widget.servlet.MasterWidgetServlet.service(MasterWidgetServlet.java:150)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.doService(ServletDefinition.java:263)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.service(ServletDefinition.java:178)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedServletPipeline.service(ManagedServletPipeline.java:91)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:62)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterDefinition.doFilter(FilterDefinition.java:168)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:58)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedFilterPipeline.dispatch(ManagedFilterPipeline.java:118)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter.doFilter(GuiceFilter.java:113)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
        at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpAprProcessor.process(AjpAprProcessor.java:429)
        at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpAprProtocol$AjpConnectionHandler.process(AjpAprProtocol.java:384)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:1665)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.InvalidRecordException: Node[1169385] is neither firstNode[969258] nor secondNode[1170375] for Relationship[3477951]
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.ReadTransaction.getMoreRelationships(ReadTransaction.java:167)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.ReadTransaction.getMoreRelationships(ReadTransaction.java:105)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.persistence.PersistenceManager.getMoreRelationships(PersistenceManager.java:108)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.NodeManager.getMoreRelationships(NodeManager.java:608)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.NodeImpl.loadMoreRelationshipsFromNodeManager(NodeImpl.java:527)
        ... 38 more
```

I got a few more of those with different IDs.

These exceptions are consistent when trying to load particular nodes, I'm certain I wasn't deleting any relationships.
I get the same error (org.neo4j.graphdb.NotFoundException: Unable to load one or more relationships ...) when inspecting these nodes in the command line shell.

It seems like a corruption of some sort. Any recommendation for how to fix it?

Comment: Would it be possible to share your db with us at neo technology? At least the messages.log but better the whole db. including the logical log files, can you put it up somewhere and send an email with the access to michael at neotechnology com ?

Comment: You may want to add a few more tags to your question to get more people to have a look.  I recommend `java` and `embedded`. Possibly `centos`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In light of what you have tried and your consistent troubles after a JVM crash, you may want to look into the possibility of a bug in Neo4J 1.8 that could be causing you the trouble. This could be caused by your relationship identifiers, like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12200889/neo4j-cypher-version-1-8-probable-bug-with-relationship-identifiers) case. Unfortunately its a bug with the 1.8 version. You may want to consider upgrading to 1.9 or using the workaround suggested in the accepted answer from the link I posted.

Hope this points you in the right direction! And best of luck coding!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the ConsistencyCheckTool ?

For example, you can check the database using (in a maven project)

```
<groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
<artifactId>neo4j-consistency-check</artifactId>
<version>1.9.M02</version>
```

as dependency and run:

```
org.neo4j.consistency.ConsistencyCheckTool.main(databasedir)
```

Or download Neo4j enterprise and use the appropriate jars.

Comment: Yes, I have tried that and the result is that there are inconsistencies.